# TMUX weird splitting mechanism

Tags: bash, zsh, tmux

I'm not sure why TMUX isn't working properly or why can't it just work out of the box. Modern terminal clients these days have `cmd+d` and `cmd-D` for splitting.

I have to press a series of keys, which is  `ctrl+/` , upon which I hear a mac "error sound" then I press `shift+'` which equals `"` and only then can I split.

Is there any way I can bind tmux to use the same keys as `ctrl-d` and `cmd-D` to fix this annoying issue?

I'm using MacOs, running TMUX on oh-my-zsh

Comment: Think about a common case: having an editor inside a tmux. Now you may understand why it is very good that tmux has keys nobody else usually use.

Comment: @GiacomoCatenazzi actually vim doesn't use the same keybindings, so I'm not sure that it would be that much of an issue

Comment: What's the difference between `Ctrl+d` and `Ctrl-D`? As far as I know, `Ctrl+/` does nothing in `tmux`, nor does `"`.  `Ctrl+D` does something completely different in the terminal on Unix systems, but maybe you're confusing the `Ctrl` key with the "Command Key" with the ⌘ symbol on it on Apple keyboards? `⌘D` splits the window in iTerm.

Comment: Ah yes, apologies, I did in fact mean CMD+D

Answer (score 4):

Tmux is actually a terminal multiplier, not a text editor. Kbd combos aren't universal or mandated by standards, but they are usually modifiable.

[Tmux man page](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/tmux.1.html) lists the default keybindings and advises they can be changed using `bind-key` and `unbind-key` commands. Those should be put into `tmux.conf`. Detailed info on `tmux.conf` file you can find in [Tmux guide](https://tmuxguide.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html).

Comment: Yeah, I acutally meant terminal clients. Warp is a good example

Comment: Well, if you hang around a bit, you'll notice that one can really never AssUMe :-)